# Jackson deserialization with @JsonUnwrapped

Tags: java, jackson

I have following classes -

```
public class Request {
   public String name;

   @JsonUnwrapped
   @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
   public DateOfBirth dateOfBirth;
}

public class DateOfBirth {
   public int day;
   public int month;
   public int year;
}
```

---

```
{
  "name" : "John Doe"
}
```

Deserealization of this JSON creates a `Request` object with `name` John Doe and `dateOfBirth` with day, month and year 0.
How can I override this behaviour so that `dateOfBirth` is null.

> Worth noting that on removing @JsonUnwrapped annotation, such JSON is deserealized into null object, so I feel like I am missing some trick here.
> **Jackson version - 2.13.1**

Comment: My actual usecase is a bit complex so I want to avoid writing custom serializer/deserializer for entire class.
I am ok with writing custom serializer/deserializer for DateOfBirth, but not sure how to emulate flattening of nested class.

Comment: How would that work without a unique JSON field? What if the JSON was `{ "day": 1 }`?

Comment: In that case DateOfBirth would be initialised with day 1, month 0, year 0, which is fine.

Comment: That might work for this case, but it's not very intuitive. And it's not how the framework is designed. Jackson doesn't know or care about uninitialized fields.

Comment: Not sure wdym. Behaviour is completely different when not using JsonUnwrapped. I do not want jackson to initialise the object when its null/not present in JSON